# Does applying PCA result in loss of information?

Tags: clustering, pca, dimensionality-reduction, standardization

I have huge dataset, each independedntly varying and has different units. Also, I want to cluster similar variables. This is the end result.

In order to do this, the first step I intend to follow is PCA(Principle Component Analysis). But few informed me that 'Since dataset is of different units and Size. It would make no sense to do PCA.'

My argument is that I would normalize the dataset and then apply PCA. But still they replied stating that it will lose information. My question here: Lets consider simple dataset by dividing with their MAX values

`X     Y      Z
999   2      70
1000  1      0
990   0.4    2`

If I normalize this (by dividing by corresponding MAX)

`X     Y       Z
.999  1       1.0
1.0   0.5     0
.99   0.2     .0285`

Now, I apply PCA Further, I revert the X,Y,Z by multiplying with their MAX values.So that values are preserved

**Please let me know if my approach is correct.
Also, How can I prevent this loss of information inspite of applying PCA**

Comment: Please do not cross-post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43225002/1060350 - asking once is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normalization you carry out doesn't affect information loss. What affects the amount of information loss is the number of principal components your create.

Assume you have N=100 variables. when you perform PCA, you are attempting to reduce N to n such that n << N

When choosing n, an important consideration is the amount of variance it explains of the original set.
For example, with n=10, you could potentially capture 85% of the variance, for n=20, capture 93% of variance and for n=50 capture 95% of variance

At this point, you would conclude, that after achieving 93% with the first 20 components, there was very little additional information in the following 30 components. This is where the information loss happens.

In exchange for reducing your dimensions from 100 to 20, you sacrifice the final 7% of variance. The good thing however, is that you get to control how much you lose by choosing how many components you want.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Arun for detailed answer.
You are right, we will bein control to choose how much info lost we intend.

Please let me know...How to extract those variables responsible for maimum variance i.e. Variables responsible for PCA1 and PCA2

In your example, Lets take I want to know which are  those variables responsible for PCA1,PCA2....PCA10 (n=10)

Basically I want to which variables correspond to 
PCA1
PCA2
.
.
:
PCA´n

By analysing these, possibly I can make a judgement regarding which variables to focus on....

Please forgive my ignorance

Comment: You need to inspect the output matrix to identify them

Comment: Thanks for response, So by Inspecting I can check which variables are highly varying by observing PCA 1
I assume
by analysing PCA1...I can extract varible list of those which vary highest
by analysing PCA2...I can extract varible list of those which vary higher
by analysing PCA3...I can extract varible list of those which vary high

Can you share github link, Where I can test with my data ?

Comment: You don't check what varies more, you look at the "component loadings" in your PCA output. The coefficients for each variable will directly tell you which variables are more influential in each component.

Comment: Oh Arun, Did you mean each PCA component has every variable in it ?

Comment: Yes, but each variable's loading/contribution can be high or low. That way you can tell which set of variables are primary contributors to reach component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56594/discussion-between-machine-learning-enthusiast-and-arun-jose).